# Как в данном случае запретить изменение элементов массива в классе из программы?

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, классы

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int Mytype;


class CArrayData
{
private:
int size;
Mytype* array;
public:
    CArrayData(int size, Mytype* array) // конструктор класса
    {
    this->array = array;
    this->size = size;
    }


CArrayData::~CArrayData() { // деструктор
    delete[] array;
    size = 0;
}

friend void out(CArrayData &CArray);

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
int n;
cout << "Введите размер массива: " << endl;
cin >> n;
Mytype *pm = new Mytype[n];
CArrayData Cl(n, pm);
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    pm[i] = Mytype (rand() % 1000)/ 10;
}
out(Cl);

pm[0] = 100500; //здесь первый элемент изменяется на 100500, как это запретить?

    out(Cl);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void out(CArrayData &CArray)
{
for (int i = 0; i < CArray.size; ++i) {
    cout << CArray.array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Сразу делать `CArrayData Cl(n, new Mytype[n]);`. Но вообще, возьмите лучше `std::vector`, а то с `new/delete` слишком просто отстрелить себе ногу. (Например, у вас класс не следует [*the rule of three*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), так что что-то вроде `CArrayData C1(n, pm), C2(C1);` приведет к неопределенному поведению из-за двойного вызова `delete` на одном и том же указателе.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Как можно инициализировать элементы в случае 'CArrayData Cl(n, new Mytype[n]);' ?

Comment: Делать это внутри класса? Мне вот что непонятно: По какому критерию вы хотите определять, можно ли менять данные? До `out` можно, а после - нет?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Хочу запретить изменять массив из main

Comment: А что, `pm[i] = Mytype (rand() % 1000)/ 10;` - не изменение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, ввести изменения в классе (заодно исправим  ошибки).

```
class CArrayData {
    const int size;       //размер должен быть костантным
    const Mytype* array;  // для хранения адреса константного обьекта
public:
    // константные обьекты инициализируются только инициализатором конструктора
    CArrayData(const int size, const Mytype* array)
        : size(size), array(array) {}// конструктор класса

    ~CArrayData() { // тут у вас была ошибка допольнительная квалификация
        delete[] array;
    }
    //...
};
```

В программе же сначала иницализируем массив, а потом присваиваем его адрес константному указателью:(**Правка**:  указателью на константный обьект)

```
Mytype *p = new Mytype[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    p[i] = Mytype (rand() % 1000)/ 10;
}
const Mytype* pm = p;
CArrayData Cl(n, pm);   
pm[0] = 100500; //невозможно изменять
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, но в последнее предложение требует правки

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще, просто перенёс инициализацию массива в конструктор, вроде больше элементы не меняются

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int Mytype;

class CArrayData
{
    int size;
    Mytype* array;  
public:
    CArrayData(int size, Mytype* array) // конструктор класса
    {
        cout << "Constructor\n";
        this->size = size;
        this->array = new Mytype[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            this->array[i] = (rand()%1000)/10;
        }
    }


    ~CArrayData() { 
        cout << "Destructor\n";
        delete[] array;
    }

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

friend void out(CArrayData &CArray);

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
int n;
cout << "Введите размер массива: " << endl;
cin >> n;
Mytype *pm = new Mytype[n];
CArrayData Cl(n, pm);
out(Cl);
pm[0] = 100500;
out(Cl);
cin.get();
cin.get();
return 0;
}

void out(CArrayData &CArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CArray.size; ++i) {
        cout << CArray.array[i] << endl;
    }
}
```